# mongodb Get the difference of days from dates having different years

Tags: mongodb

I am trying get the difference of days between two dates having different years. Like difference of days between 2015-12-26 and 2016-05-16.
In SQL I would get this below code.

```
DECLARE @s DATE ='2015-12-26',@t DATE ='2016-05-16'
SELECT DATEDIFF(N,@s,@d)
```

Can someone help me to convert this SQL Code in mongodb?

Comment: Your question with respect to MongoDB is not clear, please be more specific. Are you trying to find records in MongoDB between 2 dates?

Comment: I am trying to get the difference of days between two dates, i.e. I wanted to know the number of days between 2015-12-16 and 2016-05-16.

Comment: MongoDB is not a programming language. Perhaps a better way of asking your question is "how do I find the difference between 2 dates in javascript". Your question is lacking context of what you are doing and what you are actually trying to accomplish. What units to you want the result in? What are you *actually* trying to do with MongoDB.

Comment: @helmy : The query is simple and much straight forward. I trying to push  the count of days between two dates.
In very layman language 
Calculate the number of days existing between 2016-07-10 and 2016-07-20.
The result would be an int value like 10 or 11.
Your suggestion of asking the question "how do I find the difference between 2 dates in javascript" gives me difference in milliseconds or seconds when searched in Google. It seems your suggestion is very generic.

Comment: Many of the db query languages are also not programming languages. However, they have the ability to calculate these. I am curious to know whether it can be accomplished in mongodb or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since mongodb gives the difference in milliseconds, I have calculated the milliseconds for each day and divided with difference of milliseconds between two dates. See below example for reference:

```
>var s =ISODate("1996-12-31"), t=ISODate(), diff = Math.round((t-s)/(1000 * 3600 * 24))
>print(diff)
7140
```